# What is the difference between mappedName and lookup attributes of @Resource annotation in EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I'm confused between two attributes of `@Resource` annotation.

Java Documentations says :

**mappedName :** A product specific name that this resource should be mapped to. The name of this resource, as defined by the name element or defaulted, is a name that is local to the application component using the resource. (It's a name in the JNDI java:comp/env namespace.) Many application servers provide a way to map these local names to names of resources known to the application server. This mapped name is often a global JNDI name, but may be a name of any form.

**lookup :** The name of the resource that the reference points to. It can link to any compatible resource using the global JNDI names.

> My Question is how to choose between **mappedName** and **lookup**, 
>   based on what criteria?

Answer (score 10):

Just as it says `mappedName` is product specific and is not supported by many application servers. So for now you should use `lookup` as it should be portable and cross platform. You specify global JNDI of the given resource.