# jndi resource in Tomcat without java:/comp/env/ prefix

Tags: java, tomcat7, websphere, jndi, spring-java-config

In Tomcat any jndi resources defined in context.xml have prefix `java:/comp/env/`. In Websphere they don't. There're quite a few resources that we are injecting with

```
@Resource(mappedName="...")
private Queue queue1;
```

and it's a pain to configure them twice for local and managed environments.
I would like to configure it to have only only @Resource injection that will work for all environments. That's the point of using jndi after all.

There are ways to configure Tomcat to define a global jndi resource but they all involve changing server.xml, which we can't do since it's a gradle tomcat plugin.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect without modifying server.xml in Tomcat?

Comment: Note, the prefix required by the EE specs is `java:comp/env/`, not `java:/comp/env/` as used by some application servers.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere ignores mappedName see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036677/3701228), so you can have there whatever you like for Tomcat, but for WebSphere use `lookup=jndiName`. The `java:comp/env/` prefix is used for resource references, or resource definitions embedded in the application. It shouldn't be used as JNDI name for global objects defined in server configuration.

For WebSphere you can also use binding file `(ibm-web-bnd.xml` in the `WEB-INF`), and map there your reference to the JNDI name defined in the server configuration e.g.

```
// In code use just resource with name
@Resource(name="myQueue")    // this defines reference name which will be bound to jndi name using binding file
private Queue queue;


// binding file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd 
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

    <resource-env-ref name="myQueue" binding-name="jms/myQ" />
</web-bnd>
```

Comment: Thanks Gas for the answer. I still can't get it to work. First WAS doesn't ignore MappedName, even if I set name or lookup to something else I still get ` No bean named &amp;#39&#59;java:comp/env/jms/myQcf&amp;#39&#59; is defined: not found in JNDI environment`

I mean I can get it to work in Websphere, it's not a problem. The problem is to make it work both in Websphere and Tomcat (without changing server.xml)

Comment: It's WAS 8.5.5.5 I am talking about

Comment: @Leo Where are you using that `java:comp/env` name?

Comment: I tried `@Resource(mappedName="java:comp/env/jms/qcf1", name=""jms/qcf1")`
together with ibm-web-bnd.xml as you suggested. Tried `lookup` instead of `name` as well.

Comment: @Leo If you created `@Resource(mappedName="java:comp/env/jms/qcf1", name="jms/qcf1")`, then you have to have in the bnd file `resource-env-ref name="jms/qcf1" binding-name="JNDINameInLibertyServerXML"